# Calendar View with Market Days in Xamarin.iOS (Month/Year Style calendar display)

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I want to know if any of you know some component/binding/etc that display a calendar in a month and let you mark certain cells with different color/place an image/etc.

I have been checking the component TimeSquare Calendar but maybe is that i'm new but the sample just looks too minimal for me, what i think is that this component was maked having in mind to use it with an ActionSheet or something like that, i can't find the way to mark certain days (but i can change the background color very easy (which is very cool)).

Also i know that i can make it with the Tapku Binding but, again, i don't know Objective C, and all the samples i found are only Objective C.

Do you have some tutorial or another solution for this?

Comment: Do you want iOS 7 style calendar or previous styling?

Comment: Well, an iOS 7 approach would be the best case, but if there's another kind of solution, i'm open to try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [this](https://github.com/escoz/monotouch-controls) iOS 6 style calendar in one of my apps. It is pretty old but it does work. If the monotouch ones are too minimal, then you might have to take an obj-C and use that. You would have to create your own monotouch bindings for it though.

Comment: I will try your solution and will let you know, thanks

Comment: So sorry for the delay in the response, i test the code of escoz and works pretty well, i'm kinda new to delegates and those stuff and so it cost me a little bit to understand how that work, but i can do what i want, even i change the background of the calendar to complain to my  theme. Thanks Valdetero